# Problem with matplotlib (anaconda) update

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm having an issue with the version of my matplotlib. I don't understand why, since I downloaded and installed my new Ubuntu and anconda just last week.

I was getting an error in one of my notebooks in a legend settings, where I realized the my newly installed matplotlib version is 2.2.2. Although it was odd, I tried to update it using

> $ conda update matplotlib

in the terminal which did basically nothing. So I tried the command

> $ pip install --upgrade matplotlib

this one did update it to 3.1.1, but now I got the error that other packages (e.g. Pandas) were not installed.

I tried to fix that by going to the navigator directly and installing the packages I could think of one by one. It worked, but matplotlib was reverted back to 2.2.2.

To get out of this mess I uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled it again. Now matplotlib is still 2.2.2.

I would be grateful if anyone could tell me what the source of the problem is and/or how to solve it. Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Something like this would happen if one of the packages you installed requires matplotlib 2.2.2. In such case conda would downgrade matplotlib such that all versions match. It's often a good idea to create an environment in one rush, for example `conda create -n myenv python=3.7 matplotlib=3.1.1 pandas=0.25 pyqt [any further packages you need]`. In this way conda would directly tell you about a potential conflict.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Turned out when installing the base environment I had used an old version in the command while just copy-pasting from online instructions.
So I gather from your comment it'd be a good practice to get used to having  separate environments for different projects?

Comment: You can also always work with the `(base)` environment and use further environments only for debugging.